# What vegetable seeds should be planted right now?

Tags: vegetables, plant-recommendations, germination, planting-times, leaf-vegetables

I have a few outdoors vegetable boxes and live in the San Francisco Bay Area.  To get a head start for the growing season, I would like to start by planting seeds indoors using a heating mat.

What are good vegetable seeds to plant now?

Comment: What size of vegetable boxes? Pictures would be awesome

Comment: They are 10 feet by 6 feet so fairly big.  I am just not sure if it is too early to start tomatoes or chilis vs. kale and cucumbers.  How do I sequence seed germination for optimal results?

Comment: Are they raised beds or boxes with bottoms? How deep if boxes? What season is it now? What zone is the SF bay area?

Comment: Depth is about 6-8 inches and the bottom is soil.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you ask yourself what wegetable you should grow at a given time, you should use a seasonality table like [this one](http://www.thompson-morgan.com/static-images/tandm/in-the-garden/veg-seed-guide.jpg). This kind of document can help you to chose and optimize your cultures by planning at month scale every phase of your cultivated vegetables. **Find a similar document at a local gardening store to be sure it is suitable to your location**.

To answer your question, you could plant :

- Leeks and other member of the onion family,
- Lettuce and similars (endive, chicoree),
- Large leaves vegetables like spinach, cabbage or rhubarb.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on seasonality table. I was not aware of this thing. Just what I need.